# Updating mysql data in VB.NET not working

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm currently working on a test project in VB.NET (still learning) and I'm having a problem with update query in mysql. It simply doesn't update selected data and it doesn't show any errors. I'm using DataGridView to present data values from mysql, and when I click on the data row in DataGridView, selected data displays into the Form that I'm using to insert data into mysql database. Below that form I created a button that is supposed to update data when I change TextBox values, but it doesn't. Here's the button code:

```
 Try
        Konekcija.Open()
        Dim Query As String

        'Provjera unsosa'
        If TextBox_Ime.Text.Length = 0 Or TextBox_Prezime.Text.Length = 0 Or TextBox_Datum.Text.Length = 0 Or TextBox_Mjesto.Text.Length = 0 Or TextBox_Grad.Text.Length = 0 Or TextBox_Fakultet.Text.Length = 0 Or TextBox_Smjer.Text.Length = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Molimo popunite sva polja", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            Query = "update proba.studenti set Ime='" & TextBox_Ime.Text & "', Prezime='" & TextBox_Prezime.Text & "', Datum_Rodjenja='" & TextBox_Datum.Text & "',Mjesto_Rodjenja= '" & TextBox_Mjesto.Text & "', Mjesto_Stanovanja='" & TextBox_Grad.Text & "', Fakultet='" & TextBox_Fakultet.Text & "',Smjer= '" & TextBox_Smjer.Text & "' where Ime='" & TextBox_Ime.Text & "' "
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Konekcija)
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
            MessageBox.Show("Uspješna izmjena podataka", "Uspješna izmjena", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            TextBox_Ime.Clear()
            TextBox_Prezime.Clear()
            TextBox_Datum.Clear()
            TextBox_Mjesto.Clear()
            TextBox_Grad.Clear()
            TextBox_Fakultet.Clear()
            TextBox_Smjer.Clear()
        End If
        Konekcija.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Konekcija.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: You need to use parameterized commands to avoid SQL Injection and it will also help get your syntax correct. I don't know what the problem is from the information you have shown but `ExecuteNonQuery` is more appropriate than `ExecuteReader` for an update statement.

Comment: Sorry for poor explanation, not native English speaker. So I kinda realized what my problem was, I was changing data value of a textbox that was in my WHERE clause, so it wouldn't match and data wasn't updated. I think I just have to change my WHERE clause to something else.

Anyway, thanks for your answer, I will lookup for a statement that you suggested.

Comment: You should still follow what @crowcoder said and use parameters...You are learning and should learn the right way a not the hard and unsecured way you are using right now.

Comment: please remove unnecessary tags such as datagridview

Comment: Do not open your connection until just before you use it. (right before Command. Execute...) You open a connection and then do validation and possibly show a message box. The user went to lunch and your connection is left flapping in the breeze. Actually, I think it will time out but connections are precious and should be designed to Open and Close quickly.